# How do I run a stored procedure in ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

How to use stored procedure in ADO.NET Entity Framework?

My Table : MyCustomer

```
Columns:
CustomerID    PK   int 
Name               nvarchar(50)
SurName            nvarchar(50)
```

My stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_MyCustomerAdd]
(@Name nvarchar(50),
@SurName nvarchar(50)
)
as 
begin
  insert into dbo.MyCustomer([Name], SurName) values(@name,@surname)
end
```

My C# code

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   entityContext.MyCustomerAdd(textName.Text.Trim(), textSurName.Text.Trim());
   entityContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'TestAdonetEntity2Model.MyCustomer'. A
>   member of the type, 'CustomerID', does
>   not have a corresponding column in the
>   data reader with the same name.

Error occured below the last code line (call to ExecuteFunction):

```
global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter surNameParameter;
if ((surName != null))
{
   surNameParameter = new global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("SurName", surName);
}
else
{
   surNameParameter = new global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("SurName", typeof(string));
}
<b>return base.ExecuteFunction<MyCustomer>("MyCustomerAdd", nameParameter, surNameParameter);</b>
```

Added is ok. Every added process is ok. But after editing, above error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do it a function import with the EF tooling and calling the imported function like

```
DataContext.MyFunctionName(storedProcedureParamer1, storedProcedureParamer2)
```

[How to: Import a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess (I haven't used EF with stored procs): wouldn't the name of the function used in "ExecuteFunction" have to be the same as the stored proc's name??

```
return base.ExecuteFunction("MyCustomerAdd", nameParameter, surNameParameter);

ALTER procedure [dbo].[proc_MyCustomerAdd]
```

Can you try to use:

```
return base.ExecuteFunction("proc_MyCustomerAdd", nameParameter, surNameParameter);
```

Does that make any difference?

Marc

Comment: i find solution. Thanks alot.

Comment: You can change sp name in C# " proc_MyCustomerAdd--->MyCustomerAdd"

Comment: Yes, you can change the name of the procedure in C# - but the stored proc is still called "proc_MyCustomerAdd", and when calling base.ExecuteFunction, I understand you have to give it the name of the stored procedure - no matter what your C# function is called....

Comment: @Penguen if you 'find solution' you should really post it as an answer and accept it for other people to see.

Answer (score 0):

To call Stored Procedures for query operations you can use SqlQuery in Entityframework which is very helpful

```
_dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<EntityType>("sp_name",parameters).ToList();
```

For Executenonquery Operations(Transactions) you can use

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
                    @"UPDATE tblname SET Rating = 5" + 
                        " WHERE Name LIKE '%Entity Framework%'" 
                    );
```

Please note that _dbContext object of your Context class inherits from DbContext Class of Entityframework